# Do I have to use integration to solve this exercise?

Tags: calculus, integration

everybody, I am doing an exercise but I am not quite sure if the way I am going to resolve is the right one. Can I have your advice on it, please?

*Exercise:
Thanks to the new acquisition of advanced equipment, a company estimates that its customers will vary at a rate of f(t), where t is the number of years since the acquisition of this new equipment. If this company is right, how many customers will it have increased 16 years after this new acquisition?*

**What I think I should do is, I calculated the integral of f(t) from 0 to 16.**

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: thank you @DougM.